# Combining little-o notation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, sequence-of-function

Suppose we have $$f_{m}(n) = \frac{1}{n}g_{m}(n) + o(\frac{1}{n})$$ where the little-o notation is uniform in the variable $m$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Under what conditions is $f(m,n) = o(\frac{1}{n})$?  Under what further conditions (if any) is the little-o error for $f_{m}(n) = o(\frac{1}{n})$ uniform in $m$?

This problem is trying to ask us about what order $g_{m}(n)$ is.  I think that $f_{m}(n) = o(\frac{1}{n})$ provided $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}g_{m}(n)$ exists.  For the second part, I am not sure whether $g_{m}(n)$ needs to have uniformity in $m$ for its error.